# Selecting element by two classes and changing their css property ONLY for that particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have 3 divs

```
<div class="class1"></div>

<div class="class2"></div>

<div class="class1 class2"></div>
```

Is there a javascript or jquery way to change some css property of class1 and class2 ONLY for the third div (one with both classes) without affecting other divs that have one of those classes (like the first two), and WITHOUT using id selector? Basicly, I want javascript to select element that have both class1 and class2 and change some of their properties so it can effect only that particular element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, quite simple:

```
var $elem = $('div.class1.class2');
```

A CSS selector that requires both classes to be set on the element.